# cant download ANYTHING on My LG G2 anymore

Tags: applications, settings

My phone went in for repairs and since then I am unable to update or re-install whatsapp or chrome. I go to google play store to download whatsapp but when I click the install button nothing happens, its the same when chrome prompts Me to update, I click updaye but nothing happends, I can see that the button to install is responding when I press it but nothing happens after. is this something to do with settings or drivers or what?

Comment: my android version is 4.4.2

Comment: This may seem outrageous but sometimes unsteady internet connection can cause this problem too. Take it from the guy who has actually experienced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur sometimes when your phone is doing a large amount of updates. Especially after a factory reset. Check to make sure there are not a large amount of apps being updated. You would check that in the play store under my apps. If there is a large amount of updates in que, you may want to stop them and download them over wifi only.